# My Links Are Not Working

Tags: html, css

My links worked before, but now they aren't working. Is there a particular syntax error in this code? Thanks.

```html
 <p>A page dedicated to the mediocrity that is me.</p>
         <a class="photo_hover3" href="AboutMe.html"><img src="images/10551720_896406100374418_8341950779733681498_o.jpg" width="240" height="290" alt="picture1" onmouseover="src='images/image1.jpg'" onmouseout="src='images/10551720_896406100374418_8341950779733681498_o.jpg'"/></a>
         <a href="AboutMe.html"><span class="button">Read more</span></a>
       </section>
      <section class="group2">
         <h3>Classes</h3>
         <p>A page on the classes I'm taking Spring Semester.</p>
         <a class="photo_hover3" href="Classes.html"><img src="images/black-tarheel-sign-jpg.jpg" width="240" height="290" alt="picture2" onmouseover="src='images/image2.jpg'" onmouseout="src='images/black-tarheel-sign-jpg.jpg'"/></a>
         <a href="Classes.html"><span class="button">Read more</span></a>   
       </section>
      <section class="group3">
         <h3>Interests</h3>
         <p>A page describing my hobbies and interests.</p>
         <a class="photo_hover3" href="Interests.html"><img src="images/blackwhite,camera,canon,hands,nails,photography-eec2d4683bab11e4adc6fd271cda2979_h.png" width="240" height="290" alt="picture3" onmouseover="src='images/image3.png'" onmouseout="src='images/blackwhite,camera,canon,hands,nails,photography-eec2d4683bab11e4adc6fd271cda2979_h.jpg'"/></a>
         <a href="Interests.html"><span class="button">Read more</span></a>
```

Comment: What has changed since the links worked? And what does "not working" mean? Nothing happens when you click them? Or the browser shows page not found errors? Or...?

Comment: Why do you have commas in you image src? `<img src="images/blackwhite,camera,canon...`

Comment: The links do not go to their appropriate html pages

Comment: Have you recently moved files?  My initial thought is that the file paths are no longer accurate.

Comment: Your code snippet shows that the links are working just fine

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments your links are working the problem is most likely the path that you are using. A way to check if your paths are correct is to type it directly into the browser like www.example.com/AboutMe.html/ if that takes you to the AboutMe page then your path is good if not you will need to check your folder/file structure and find where your about me page is located. If the page is in another folder then you will need to add that folder to your path like so:

```
       www.example.com/anotherfolder/AboutMe.html
```

and your link should look like this:

```
    <a href="/anotherfolder/AboutMe.html">About Me</a>
```

Comment: It worked fine, but the thing is the other pages links work fine except the one I mentioned in this post. They have the same code for the menu items.